# fetch data into labels asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, label

here is my history page:

[image]

code behind:

```
public static string cs = "Server=PAULO;Database=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security=true";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["New"] != null)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
                con.Open();

                string sql = "SELECT * FROM CustomerDetails Where CustomerName = '" + Session["New"] +"'";
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);




                Label2.Text += Session["New"].ToString();
                linkLogout.Visible = true;
                //linkOrderHistory.Visible = true;
                Label2.Visible = true;
                linkViewProfile.Visible = true;
                grid.DataSource = dt;
                grid.DataBind();
            }
        }

    }
    private void CustomBindData()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        con.Open();

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM CustomerDetails Where CustomerName = '" + Session["New"] + "'";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        grid.DataSource = dt;
        grid.DataBind();
    }
```

When i click on the the "view details" it shows me this:

[image]

What i want to happen is to get the session ID and the Id and put it in my label. so far i got this:

```
string strConnString = "Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True";
    string str;
    SqlCommand com;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        con.Open();
        str = "select Id from CustomerDetails Where CustomerName = '"+Session["New"].ToString()+"'";
        com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            reader.Read();
            Label3.Text = reader["Id"].ToString();
            Label2.Text = Session["New"].ToString();
```

The session is fine ("faufao") and is has some values in my label ("13"):
[image]

but when i try to click on the Id 22, it still shows the Id 13? any tricks on this?

btw here is my database:
[image]

currenyly, i got this:

[image]

what am i missing? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str = "select Id from CustomerDetails Where CustomerName = '"+Session["New"].ToString()+"'";
```

This query will return many `id` . So when you wrote   `Label3.Text = reader["Id"].ToString()`, It will return first row `(13)`

You first read all `id` and put them in list and use them .

```
List<string> ListOfId = new List<string>();
While( reader.Read())
{
    ListOfId.Add( reader["Id"].ToString());
}
```

The better practice is get `id` using `QueryString`

```
Label3.Text =  Request.QueryString[0];
```

Or

```
Label3.Text =  Request.QueryString["Id"];
```

Comment: can you show me full code sir? where will i put the ListOfId?

Comment: Use query string to get Id .I don't know what you want to do exactly .but this will help you

Comment: i have an error on ListOfId, what do i need to declare or call sir?

Comment: got the idea. all i want is to get all the Id's (because i need to compare them with something later) and as you have said store it in the reader.

Comment: You must declare that  `List<string> ListOfId = new List<string>();`